# OpenJDK for production and LTS?

Tags: java

My understanding from "Do you have to pay to use Java?" of  [Java programming language Free](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/can-you-still-use-the-java-programming-language-for-free-what-you-need-to-know/)
is that I can go for OpenJDK(version 11) build provided I don't need LTS as both OpenJDK and commercial version are identical in terms of features. If I need to purchase LTS(Long term support) either I have to purchase support for OpenJDK or upgrade to same version of  "commercial Oracle JDK build". Is that correct ?

Another question is why I need LTS ?
I think if we don't take LTS then any we don't get any  support/patch for defects( or security patch). Right ?

Comment: "provided I don't need LTS " re-read the phrase (emphasis mine): "unless you want long-term support **from Oracle**".

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I was going through oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/price-lists/…. Just wondering(out of curosity) is there any logic of relating  price to number of cores ? Should not it be related to jvm instance instead of cores or user or something more logical?

Comment: Just a guess, but many cores means many users, so you're priced based on how "successful" you are, so to speak.

Comment: Well single core can can serve many users(load). But probably assumption is if server is of high configuration then higher load

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a [blog article discussing that topic in early 2019](https://labs.consol.de/development/2019/02/05/oracle-license-is-the-free-lunch-over.html).

First, as far as I know, the OpenJDK team does not offer any premium support.

Second, normally one goes to the LTS for longterm support, mainly security updates.

Third, [Oracle will only hand over the code for the LTS version to the OpenJDK team and only after the LTS has reached its end of life](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-dev/2018-August/001833.html). This means that the OpenJDK community has to keep up with changes on their own.

Now to the topic on the JDKs being identical. They both pass the [JCK](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/JckAccess/) and thus can be used as drop-in replacement for each other. The implementations, however, may vary.

There is a host of JDK providers, all with different support plans. Fact of the matter is, [there is no free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem). If one wants support, one has to pay.

A remark on your post: Please limit yourself to [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: you said `The implementations, however, may vary` . Does it mean commercial and openjdk implementation of java 11(an example) may be different though they are released on same day by same company. Just wondering why they would do that ?

Comment: Well yes, they are. The behaviour is definded in the JCK. Each company/team releasing a JCK-compatible JDK has to pass the JCK tests. The code is the property of the respective company/team and may be closed-source and subject of copyright. That is the reason why there may be varying implementations.

Comment: Because once OpenJDK is out, Oracle doesn't (officially) touch that code anymore, so it's up to OpenJDK providers to apply patches and stuff. Also: because otherwise no-one would pay up.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Exactly My question is implementation may vary after release but at the time of release it will be same ?

Comment: @user3198603 if you're talking about patches to a particular version, nope. Oracle will release when they fix a bug, OpenJDK will release when the particular implementation you're using fixes a bug.

Comment: @user3198603 at the time of release, Oracle is probably the only company having a JDK ready. Keep in mind that there is a host of companies/teams producing JDKs. To name a few: Amazon (Corretto), RedHat, SAP (SapMachine), OpenJDK-Team, Azul (Zulu).

Comment: @Turing85 I start getting it. Say Java 11 was released by oracle on September 2018 . It means I have to wait for OpenJDK 11 as it may take sometime to come out with their implementation by OpenJDK providers ?

Comment: @user3198603 most probably, yes. I do not follow the release of OpenJDK versions, but I would not be surprised if OpenJDK only releases Java 11 after the public update period of six months has passed and Oracle has handed over the codeline to the OpenJDK-project.

Comment: @user3198603 I have to eat my own words here: For the first six month of an LTS-release, the OpenJDK-releases will come directly from Oracle. Then, after this period, Oracle hands over the code to the OpenJDK team, which will continue working on the code until it receives the code of the next LTS. Oracle will continue to support its own code line of the LTS for another 2.5 years, but will develop it as closed-source.

Comment: Thanks. when you say ` OpenJDK team` is it separate team(some  community) as I do not see any mention with this name at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK ?

Comment: The "team" is split into multiple groups. And yes, companies are involoved (RedHat and Azul have a long-standing history supporting Java for example, IBM and SAP are involved aswell). If you want names, look at the [governing board](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/gb/).

Comment: Ok. One last thing relating to pricing . I was going through oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/price-lists/…. Just wondering why pricing is related to number of cores ? Should not it be related to jvm instance instead of cores ?

Comment: This is a question I cannot answer. Pricing is at Oracle's discretion. Only they can answer this question. My guess is: because they can.

Comment: @Turing85 From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history looks like, Free public support/updates are provide for current LTS release till next LTS Release. Right ?

Answer (score 5):

**OpenJDK** is a free and open-source implementation of the Java Platform. The implementation is licensed under the GNU General Public License. You are free to use at any environment. But you won't get any kind of support from the Oracle and you've to rely on open communities support, later can be best than the OEM support some times.

**LTS** is a product life cycle management policy in which a stable release of software is maintained for a longer period of time than the standard edition. You get security updates for some good number of years.

***Do you have to pay to use Java?***

Answer is yes, Iff you use Oracle JDK for business, commercial, or production purposes.

Answer is No, if you use OpenJDK irrespective purpose or environment.

**PS**: this is all about licensing and it can change over a period of time.

Comment: Do companies have to pay also when using Oracle JDK 8 or prior versions? Does the new Oracle licensing model apply for all JDKs?

Answer (score 3):

LTS is supported for 3 years and will receive updates until it expires. When you use openjdk you need not pay for support or patches. I always go with LTS like java 11.

The non-LTS version will have newer features but they are short lived like 6 months. They don’t receive updates for long rather it is expected to upgrade to next version. Security patches are available on same version or next version.

If you don’t have a special usecase then open jdk is more than enough

Comment: I was going through http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/price-lists/java-se-subscription-pricelist-5028356.pdf. Just wondering why pricing is related to number of cores ? Should not it be related to jvm instance instead of cores ?

Comment: That is Oracle way. Database is priced per core

Comment: From en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history looks like, Free public support/updates are provide for current LTS release till next LTS Release. Right ?

Comment: Yes for OpenJDK.

Comment: Why would someone go for LTS version of JDK, if one is using OpenJDK? Is there any advantage of getting LTS OpenJDK 11 over non LTS OpenJDK?

Comment: When you use LTS version you would just stay up to date with security patches and rest of Java features stay supported for you. When you don't use LTS version then you are supposed to upgrade the java as new major releases come because it is expected that old release had bugs.